# Convert servlet code to jsp code

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have servlet code for displaying records from the table.
I want to translate same code into jsp code.
Any one please help me for converting SERVLET code into JSP code.
The servlet is working fine

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.hai.jsp.Emp;
import com.hai.jsp.EmpDao;  
@WebServlet("/ViewServlet")  
public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
               throws ServletException, IOException {  
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();  
        out.print("<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'></head><body>");
        out.println("<a href='index.html'><b>ADD NEW EMPLOYEE</b></a>");  

        out.println("<h1 style='color: #ff3399' align='center'><u>EMPLOYEES LIST</u></h1>");  

        List<Emp> list=EmpDao.getAllEmployees();  

        out.print("<div id='div1'><table border='1' width='100%' style='color: #ff3399'");  
        out.print("<tr><th>Id</th><th>FIRST NAME</th><th>LAST NAME</th><th>GENDER</th><th>DESIGNATION</th><th>MOBILE</th><th>DATE OF BIRTH</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>COUNTRY</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>");  
        for(Emp e:list){  
         out.print("<tr><td>"+e.getId()+"</td><td>"+e.getFName()+"</td><td>"+e.getLName()+"</td> <td>"+e.getgender()+"</td><td>"
        +e.getdesignation()+"</td><td>"+e.getmobile()+"</td><td>"+e.getdob()+"</td><td>"+e.getaddress()+"</td><td>"
                +e.getCountry()+"</td><td><a href='test?id="+e.getId()+"' >EDIT</a></td><td><a href='DeleteServlet?id="
                 +e.getId()+"'>DELETE</a></td></tr>");  
      }  

        out.print("</table></div>");
        out.print("<div id='div2'>"
                + "</div> ");
        out.print("</body></html>");

        out.close();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: what's stopping you?  add `list` to your request, put the `out.print` stuff into jsp - convert to use JSTL

Comment: Thanks for responding mypost  Scary Wombat...I want to convert same servlet code into JSP please help me for converting